# Снижение нагрузки на mysql сервер

Tags: php, mysql

Если, к примеру, на сайте сидит одновременно 3к человек, каждые 30 секунд от каждого из них как минимум 1 запрос, а возможно и 5-6, так как сделать чтобы не упал сервер? Предполагаю нужно сделать файл, куда записывать запросы, и обробатывать потом по 300 запросам, например, разумеется будет задержка с обновлением данных, но это не страшно. Или я не правильно говорю? Как снизить нагрузку на mysql Сервер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первую очередь, зависит от сути запросов. Выборки это, вставки, или обновления.

Выборки можно оптимизировать пересмотром запросов, индексами (подозреваю, что уже сделано) и кэшированием результатов. Для кэша — memcached в помощь, опасайтесь только [dogpile effect](http://habrahabr.ru/post/43540/), вешайте на обновление семафор.

Для вставок и обновлений зависит от требований к транзакционности, каким свойствам ACID они (и сопровождающие выборки) должны удовлетворять. Если требований нет (скажем, банальный инкретемн счетчиков или вставка рядов логов) — можно складывать их в промежуточный буфер (memcached или Redis, но можно и файлы), откуда периодически пачками отправлять в базу.

Затем, в ряде случаев, возможен шардинг. Если в структуре сайта есть однотипные элементы (например, статьи или комнаты чата), то их можно разнести по разным серверам. Например, на пальцах — сервер A будет обрабатывать статьи с четными ID, а B — с нечетными. Разумеется, сервера должны быть на разных машинах.

Ну и улучшение железа тоже не стоит сбрасывать со счетов. Проблема решается комплексно, универсального «сделайте вот это и все будет хорошо» тут нет.

Приводите более конкретные примеры и можно будет попробовать дать более конкретные ответы.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня ведётся статистика кликов по ссылкам, кешировать страницы нельзя, т.к. они очень динамичны. Ну в принципе я понял например прибавление счётчика можно сделать 10 раз по +1, а можно 1 раз по +10, но с задержкой. Разумеется второе лучше.

Comment: Возьмите memcached и вынесите счетчики туда, рекомендую. У memcached есть атомарная команда `add`, самое оно для таких задач. А раз в N времени эти счетчики сбрасывайте в БД. При этом если нужны живые данные — их можно и из memcached брать. Если вдруг memcached рухнет — потеряете несброшенные данные за до N единиц времени (поэтому N выбирается как компромисс между нагрузкой и возможными потерями).
Альтернатива — Redis — помощнее, но на вкус. Только его или на отдельной машине от SQL-сервера держать или отрубить сохранение в RDB, оставив один AOF или, в идеале, вообще никакой персистентности.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "оптимизация" Вам знакомо? Нужно оптимизировать запросы, очевидно. И т.к. в метках указан ещё и язык. То почитайте про кэширование.

Comment: Если у него ресурс дорос до 3k одновременных пользователей, то, подозреваю, что структура БД и запросы уже достаточно причесаны.